# Ruby date comparison in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a ruby array end_dates that might look like...

```
end_dates =  [Sat, 14 Dec 2013, Sat, 14 Dec 2013, Sat, 14 Dec 2013, Fri, 13 Dec 2013, Sat, 14 Dec 2013, Sat, 14 Dec 2013, Sat, 14 Dec 2013]
```

...and I need a conditional statement that tells me weather a given date is greater than any of the dates in the array. So it might look like...

my_date = Thursday, 12 Dec 2013

compares my_date to all dates in the array and returns true if any dates are less than my_date

```
if my_date > end_dates
  do stuff
end
```

Comment: is the data in `my_date` a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if end_dates.any? { |end_date| end_date < my_date } 
  # do stuff
end`

Answer (score 2):

Not as efficient as using `any?`, but simpler:

```
if my_date > end_dates.min
  ...
end
```

If you keep the min value somewhere, and reuse it:

```
min = end_dates.min
...
if my_date > min
  ...
end
```

then it would not be inefficient.